# Вставка больших svg файлов в html

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Проблема в следующем имеется карта map.svg(1,5Мб). При Ховере на отдельные регионы они подсвечиваются или при других действиях.Сделал так: минимизировал файл, вставил svg код прямо в страницу, дал классы нужным мне  и все работает так как мне нужно, но конечный .html размером 650Кб, что как мне кажется много. Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ни как, к примеру есть проекты на threejs или ещё круче на webgl там вообще даже не у всех работает это, но в общем сказать обсуждение раздувать нельзя здесь ...

Comment: Ну можно ещё сам HTML файл минимизировать.

Comment: можно в iframe или в object  подгружать - тогда вес уменьшится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не с того начали. Изначально занимаются уменьшением объемов SVG например с использованием [SVGO](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), удалением лишних контрольных точек в файле, сокращения размеров PATH, инструментами оптимизации векторных редакторов, удаления лишних слоев, сокращения цветовой палитры, а уже потом добавлением всего остального.

Теперь можно только делать отложенную погрузку данного тега `<svg>` скажет по доскроллу к области его отображения. Ну и минимизации и кешировании html... но то припарки.